# Specify dependency with classifier in Zeppelin

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, emr, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to play around with sentiment analysis on EMR with Zepplin and Stanford NLP.

I have added `edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.8.0`, however, I cannot figure out how to add a dependency with a classifier.

I am getting this error `edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL`.

It shows up because I need this package (in sbt format) `libraryDependencies += "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.8.0"classifier "models"`

How can I specify this dependency in Zeppelin?

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Answer (score 4):

To add the dependency to the language models, use the following format in the Dependencies section of the of the Spark Interpreter configuration (Interpreters -> Spark -> Edit -> Dependencies):

> groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version

In your case it should work with

> edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:models:3.8.0